# Always scroll a full line in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, scroll, qwidget, qtextedit

I have a QTextEdit with many lines and a vertical scrollbar. I want the vertical scrolling to always scroll full lines (as for example Windows Notepad does).

Right now, it has the default behavior of scrolling by pixels and not lines, so it's possible to scroll into the middle of a line for example, which I don't want to happen.
Example of the undesired behavior:

[image: Example of the undesired behavior]

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: If it is suitable for your needs, you might try `QPlainTextEdit`.

Comment: I believe QPlainTextEdit doesn't support QSyntaxHighlighter, which I'm also using, so that is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried it? `QPlainTextEdit` implements `document()`, so you should be good to go.

Comment: It looks like I have been mistaken about what QPlainTextEdit is capable of. I think this might work, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question as I managed to solve it, at least for my usecase.
It turns out this is exactly what `QPlainTextEdit` was meant to do, so switching to it from `QTextEdit` was all that was needed.